# How to prevent the Power button to shutdown directly the system?

Tags: acpi

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.10. When I press my power button, my computer immediately shuts down. In Ubuntu 13.04 I got a nice menu, where I could choose what to do. It is gone now and I want it back. Here is my `/etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh` [in pastebin.](http://pastebin.com/fTcEuum6)

I already did

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-WORD 'interactive'
```

where `WORD` is `hibernate`, `power`, `sleep` and `suspend`.

Comment: I went through my `/etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh` and found out that it just does nothing.
The menu I’m speaking of can be summoned by the command `gnome-session-quit --power-off`

Comment: lulz.  wish i'd read your comment before i went on a wild goose chase trying to find that command.

Comment: did my answer not work for you?

Comment: I upvoted your answer and I’m sure it would have worked; I reinstalled my whole system. I have had some other problems, too. This (oviously) fixed it for me.

Comment: ah, k.  just saw you stopped by the site without comment so thought the notification might've been lost.  strange, totally reinstalling fixed this?  did you download the latest 13.10?  i did a fresh install and newly had this problem.

Comment: When I upgraded to 13.10 I did a “fresh“ install, but I just took my old /home/user folder with me. Then I had the problem described above (as well as some others). After formatting my / and /home/user drives and doing a completely clean fresh install, everything worked fine. (Of course I did a backup of my important files.) Now I have a fine running system and I also minimized the size of my /home/user folder. :)

Comment: Shutting down the system (with no prompt or menu) is a quite annoying default action to have for the power button

Answer (score 46):

Check your `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` file. It should look like this:

```
[Login]
#NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
#Controllers=
#ResetControllers=cpu
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
#HandleSuspendKey=suspend
#HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
#HandleLidSwitch=suspend
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
```

Uncomment the line that says `#HandlePowerKey=poweroff` and change the value to `ignore`.

Then restart the logind with the command: `sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind` or reboot your computer.

**EDIT: how to create a new acpi handler**
Create a new file in `/etc/acpi/events/`. The content of the file should be:

```
event=<acpi_event_code>
action=<script_to_call>
```

where `<acpi_event_code>` is the code you get using the `acpi_listen` tool and `<script_to_call>` is the full path to the script you wish to call when that event happens.

They must have changed something in 13.10 because it seems that I have too few files in my /etc/accpi/events folder compared to the 13.04.

Comment: This does't bring back my beloved menu. It just does nothing when I press the power button now.

Comment: If the powerbtn.sh is actually executed whem the power button is pressed, you could try to make it execute the shutdown menu command if the X server is running and gnome is your desktop environment. Have a look at the output of the `export` command to determine which variables to test. If the powerbtn.sh script isn't executed at all, you could try to see which acpi event to bind to by running `acpi_listen` and pressing the power button. Also, perhaps there is an option in gnome to bring the power menu back, but I'm not sure as it's been a while since I last used gnome.

Comment: I tried this and the `powerbtn.sh` is (probably) not executed, because nothing happens, when I press the button. The `acpi_listen` tells me that the button triggers an acpi event. Unfortunately my volume up and down keys don’t work either. Maybe this is related?

Comment: You could try the following: `grep "<acpi_event_code>" /etc/acpi/events/*` where `<acpi_event_code>` is the code of the acpi event you saw on acpi_listen. If you get a result, view that file and see the name of the script it calls. If you don't get a result, you could try adding a new file in the `/etc/acpi/events/`. See the edited answer for more details.

Comment: Confirm that this works with 16.04 LTS on my mac.

Comment: Reminder to save your work before running `sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind` since it will abruptly kill your X session and all the programs you have running.

Answer (score 4):

jeremijah put me on the right track so kudos!

I edited `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` as recommended, but I also did [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/385716/128334).

Answer (score 3):

**If the above solutions don't work for you,**
Here is a quick work around:

- Install xtrlock

This utility does the work for you. Though this may not answer the question,
in the many solutions I'v tried (including the ones on this page) none seem to work

To install:

```
sudo apt install xtrlock
```

To use:
Type `xtrlock` in the command line. This will freeze mouse, keyboard

**To unlock type your password and press [Enter]**

---

It can also freeze your power button.

P.S *This solution is particularly useful for those who have kids and want the power button disabled for that reason.*

> xtrlock  -  Lock  X  display  until  password supplied, leaving
>   windows
>          visible
>   Source: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/man1/xtrlock.1x.html

Comment: Please expand your answer. Is this app available in the repositories? How did you install it, by command line, or via the Ubuntu Software Center? If via command line, which command did you use? Did you configure it, of so how?

Comment: `sudo apt install xtrlock -y`

Answer (score 1):

First you could edit your keymap file to change the behavior of the power button to assign it to an other key

Edit the file : `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/inet` (edit POWR key)

Then you will need to disable the power button efficiently a good method is with xinput

run `xinput --list` power buttons have their own entry... pick the device number then run

`xinput disable devnumber` something like `xinput disable 8`