# Power button in Lubuntu 13.10 will not suspend

Tags: lubuntu, shutdown, systemd-logind

I made the upgrade on my Lubuntu machine to 13.10 yesterday. Everything seemed to go smoothly except one niggling thing I can't seem to fix. Previously, I had set the power button to suspend my computer when it was pressed- I was able to set this in the Xfce Power manager.

However after the upgrade, pressing the power button will shutdown the computer rather than suspending. I did a test and checked the logs and found this when I pressed the power button:

```
auth.log:Oct 21 22:48:35 Inspiron-1564 systemd-logind[748]: Power key pressed.
auth.log:Oct 21 22:48:35 Inspiron-1564 systemd-logind[748]: Powering Off...
auth.log:Oct 21 22:48:35 Inspiron-1564 systemd-logind[748]: System is powering down.
```

I'm stuck here. Somehow systemd-logind thinks I want to shut the computer down, but I'm not sure where those settings may be. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Additionally, while [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362914/13-10-power-button-shuts-down-directly) has an answer that has a roundabout method of solving the problem, I will not accept that as an answer because it essentially doesn't work, and is not how the problem should be solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that systemd-logind is in conflict with xfce4-power-manager. This seems to resolve it for me with xubuntu on and Inspiron 9400.

- Tell systemd-logind to ignore the power button. Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>. And enter the following command to edit the file:

  gksu leafpad /etc/systemd/logind.conf

Un-comment the line for HandlePowerKey and change the value from poweroff to ignore so that it looks like this:

```
HandlePowerKey=ignore
```

- Restart the service

  sudo service systemd-logind restart
- Use `xfce4-power-manager-settings` to set the power button action

Good Luck!

Comment: fantastic! The answer was right under my nose. I'll report this to the Lubuntu devs.