# How to disable powerbutton in 13.10 minimal?

Tags: power-management, acpi

I have my IR receiver connected to the physical power button for turning on and there's a separate remote button for turning off. How to disable the power on button from shutting down the computer?

In previous Ubuntu versions I have edited /etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh but now it has now effect. My /etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh and /etc/acpi/events/powerbutton both are symlinked to /bin/false and still the power button works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit/add the following line to `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`

```
HandlePowerKey=ignore
```

Some more details here: [How to prevent the Power button to shutdown directly the system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362914/13-10-power-button-shuts-down-directly)